# Magento 2 Url Key of Configurable Simple Product are same

Tags: magento2, product, configurable-product, url, simple-product

I had migrated my store to the latest version, now I am facing an issue:
Some Configurable Simple Product have same Url key,

Below are the Simple Products of a Configurable Product:

[image]

**Is there any way to solve this?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I fixed it by using this 2 different ways:
**Solution 1:**
Create a Script to generate all products url
**Solution 2:**
Open and edit all products and save them manually.

Both Solutions solved my issue but Solution 2 is time consuming, So I followed first.

Comment: what was the script to generate all urls?